# How to make continues conversation from the previous conversation in Microsoft Bot

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

In this scenario I want to make a sequence conversation similar to FomFlow. When user click on “Yes” then move to the next reply and continue the conversation  as 1,2,3 and 4.

Assume now all the conversation is available on chat window, user will  go to the previous conversation  and select 2nd one ,click  again “Yes” on the button then will get the reply of 3rd message.

Here I am looking the solution how to continue the conversation from any card.

I have attached a sample here and want to get the following scenario :

Start 2,3,4
Start 3,4
[FormFlow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQHLB.png)

If we are using FormFlow we can build the solution but we can’t do any attachment if we are using form Flow.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend this, you are looking the bot as an app, don't forget the bots are like "state machines" to be more like real conversations. If you really want to do this then I suggest to create a dialog dispatcher that checks for an Id of every user's choice then moves on the flow according to that, but that would be difficult, maybe what you need is an app, or an API, not a bot